# Is there a standard way to compare two ranges using a predicate?

Tags: c++, c++11

Given...

```
string a; // = something.
string b; // = something else.  The two strings are of equal length.
string::size_type score = 0;
```

...what I would like to do is something like...

```
compare(a.cbegin(), a.cend(), b.cbegin(), b.cend(), [&score](const char c1, const char c2) -> void {
    if (c1 == c2) { // actually a bit more complicated in real life
        score++;
    }
});
```

...but as far as I can tell there doesn't seem to be a std::compare.  The nearest seems to be std::lexicographical_compare but that doesn't quite match.  Ditto for std::equal.  Is there really nothing appropriate in the standard library?  I suppose I could write my own (or use a plain old C style loop which is what I did but how boring :-) but I would think what I'm doing is rather common so that would be a strange omission IMO.  So my question is am I missing something?

Comment: Errr... [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) *does* take a predicate.

Comment: What sort of comparison do you wish to do? You forgot to define your requirements, except in terms of functionality that does not exist.

Comment: Why does `std::lexicographical_compare` not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a standard algorithm to compare to ranges using a predicate? Yes, `std::equal`, or `std::lexicographical_compare`.

Is there a standard algorithm to do what your code is doing? `std::inner_product` can be made to do it:

```
std::string a = "something";
std::string b = "samething";
auto score = std::inner_product(
    a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), 0,
    [](int x, bool b) { return x + b; },
    [](char a, char b) { return a == b; });
```

> but I would think what I'm doing is rather common

No, not really. If you just want to run a general function over corresponding elements in two ranges, the appropriate algorithm would be `for_each` with a [zip iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html). If anything's missing from the standard, it's the zip iterator. We don't need a special algorithm for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

It looks a bit as if you are looking for `std::mismatch()` which yields the iterators where the first difference is found (or the end, of course). It doesn't compute the difference, however, because there isn't a subtraction defined for all types. Like the other algorithms `std::mismatch()` comes in a form with a predicate and one without a predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou to all that answered.  What I was trying to do (more for my edification than anything else really) was to replace this...

```
for (string::const_iterator c1 = a.begin(), c2 = b.begin(); c1 != a.end(); ++c1, ++c2) {
    if (*c1 == *c2) {
        score++;
    }
}
```

...with snazzy new c++11 stuff :-)  I looked at equal, lexicographical_compare etc. but I guess what tripped me up was that they take a boolean predicate and if it returns false processing stops whereas I needed to process the entire ranges each time.  Then after reading the answers you gave me I had the epiphany that just because there is a return value doesn't mean I can't throw it away if I don't need it.  By simply always returning true in my lambda I can use any of the above mentioned algorithms and they will run to the end of the range.

The only thing is as I would be using the algorithms in a different way than their names suggest, it might cause maintainance problems in the future so I will just stick to my boring old loop for now but I learned something new so thanks once again.